# Reference of "permanent numbers"

Tags: reference

In the following paragraph:

> She gestures across the mass of daisies in the field. This is already
> a potent summation given the permanent numbers on Maude’s arm
> signaling a past outside the film’s time frame. But when Ashby cuts to
> a wide shot...

does "permanent numbers" refer to "daisies on Maude's arm"? If so, why does the writer use the adjective "permanent"? In my understanding, daisies could not be "permanent".

Comment: You might have given the context. From this Quora question: [In the movie Harold and Maude, what is the significance of the number on Maude's arm?](https://www.quora.com/In-the-movie-Harold-and-Maude-what-is-the-significance-of-the-number-on-Maudes-arm) ***Maude is a Holocaust survivor.** The moment where the camera zooms in and softly lingers on Maude’s wrist showing a tattoed 6 digit number is so brief a lot of people miss what is one of the most poignant clues to why Maude embraces life with such a breathless and all consuming passion.*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a historical / cultural icon, not the English language